# Como poderei colocar um número negativo em PHP?

Tags: php

Ou seja, eu tenho uma variavel x.

```
$x = 2;
```

Qual seria o comando para que conseguisse colocar o `$x = -2`?

Comment: Exatamente este. Parece não haver uma pergunta aqui, portanto se não houver esclarecimento seria melhor fechar como não clara para evitar ambiguidades de interpretação, como já está ocorrendo.

Comment: Vide resposta do Bruno Pitelli. Se pretende aplicar isso programaticamente,  é o meio ideal. Multiplicar por -1.

Comment: Obrigado @Gonçalo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um método para retornar sempre o valor negativo de um número:

```
function retornaNegativo($valor){
    return -abs($valor);
}

$x = retornaNegativo(2);
```

A função **abs** retorna sempre o valor sem o sinal, então independente do número passado como parâmetro para a função **retornaNegativo**, o retorno sempre será negativo.

Answer (score 2):

Qualquer numero negativo com um positivo, vira negativo

Multiplique por -1

$x *= -1;

Answer (score 2):

Basta igualar como o sinal de negativo na frente:

```
$x = 2;
$x = -$x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Se pretende transformar uma variável existente num valor negativo, programaticamente, multiplique por -1. Isso é matemática básica.

```
$x = 10;

/*
aqui faz as firulas e tal..

*/

//em algum ponto vc quer mudar o $x para negativo, então use

$x *= -1;
```

Quando o valor é variável, essa é a forma correta.

Se o valor for constante ou já iniciar com negativo, então basta fazer o óbvio

`$x = -10;`